# php class function not returning properly to caller

Tags: php, return

**Background**
I am writing a new database connector file for TeraWURFL which will use PDO extension. For more details on this please check

**Details**
I added a new database connector - `TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL5_Mine.php` and defined the same in the config file - `TeraWurflConfig.php` (there already are many connector files which come with TeraWURFL the value in the config file decides which one is used) -

```
public static $DB_CONNECTOR = "MySQL5_Mine";
```

I then wrote a test script to unit test all the functions of the new `TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL5_Mine.php` class file to make sure they return the same values after the changes. I am facing problem in the test script.

Everything is working fine but something is wrong with one function inside `TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL5_Mine.php` called `rebuildCacheTable()`. When I call this function from my test script, control does not return back to my test script after the return statement inside that function.  -

Code inside test script `test_connector.php` -

```
/*file inclusiong start*/
require_once '/var/cake_1.2.0.6311-beta/app/webroot/Tera-Wurfl_PDO/TeraWurfl.php';
    require_once '/var/cake_1.2.0.6311-beta/app/webroot/Tera-Wurfl_PDO/TeraWurflConfig.php';

    require_once '/var/cake_1.2.0.6311-beta/app/webroot/Tera-Wurfl_PDO/DatabaseConnectors/TeraWurflDatabase.php'; //this file is same on both setups
    require_once '/var/cake_1.2.0.6311-beta/app/webroot/Tera-Wurfl_PDO/TeraWurflLoader.php';
    require_once '/var/cake_1.2.0.6311-beta/app/webroot/Tera-Wurfl_PDO/UserAgentFactory.php';
    require_once '/var/cake_1.2.0.6311-beta/app/webroot/Tera-Wurfl_PDO/UserAgentUtils.php';
    require_once '/var/cake_1.2.0.6311-beta/app/webroot/Tera-Wurfl_PDO/WurflConstants.php';
    require_once '/var/cake_1.2.0.6311-beta/app/webroot/Tera-Wurfl_PDO/WurflSupport.php';
    require_once '/var/cake_1.2.0.6311-beta/app/webroot/Tera-Wurfl_PDO/UserAgentMatchers/UserAgentMatcher.php';

    require_once '/var/cake_1.2.0.6311-beta/app/webroot/Tera-Wurfl_PDO/DatabaseConnectors/TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL5_Mine.php';
/*file inclusiong end*/


    $wurflDbPdoObj = new TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL5_Mine();
    $wurflDbPdoObj->connect();
    $dbObj = $wurflDbPdoObj;
    echo "before call";
    var_dump($dbObj->rebuildCacheTable());
    echo "after call"; //this does not execute if new TeraWurfl() object is initiated below
```

And code inside `TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL5_Mine` -

```
class TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL5_Mine extends TeraWurflDatabase{
    ...
    ...

    public function rebuildCacheTable(){
       $rebuilder = new TeraWurfl(); //if this object is initiated, return does not happen properly
       return true; //this does not return properly. 

   }
}
```

**My debugging so far**

I verified that the object initiated by `$rebuilder = new TeraWurfl();` is a proper object.

I could narrow down to this, that if the line `$rebuilder = new TeraWurfl();` inside `TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL5_Mine` is removed, return works properly.

Also, there is no such problem if I call the same function of the existing connector class `TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL5` (I include `TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL5.php` instead of `TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL5_Mine.php` in the file inclusion part and make `public static $DB_CONNECTOR = "MySQL5";`) -

```
 $wurflDbPdoObj = new TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL5();
 $wurflDbPdoObj->connect();
 $dbObj = $wurflDbPdoObj;
 echo "before call";
 var_dump($dbObj->rebuildCacheTable());
 echo "after call"; //works
```

I also compared the `var_dump()` values of the objects created by `$rebuilder = new TeraWurfl();` in both these cases (new `TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL5_mine.php` and existing `TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL5.php`). Found no problem there.

I have no clue what is wrong with my code. Any idea??

**Updates**
Further found that the problem is inside the constructor of the `TeraWurfl.php` class. The constructor initiates an object of the database connector class again -

```
public function __construct()
{
    ...
    $dbconnector = 'TeraWurflDatabase_'.TeraWurflConfig::$DB_CONNECTOR; //return fails if this object is initiated
    if($this->db === false) $this->db = new $dbconnector;
    ...
}
```

No errors/warnings appear and `var_dump()` looks fine comparing with the existing database connector case. There too an object of that database connector class is initiated.

**Update #2 - profiling output**
I set up code profiling by following steps as mentioned in http://kpayne.me/2012/02/04/use-register_tick_function-to-profile-your-code/ with a little modification to also display the class name in the output, and here are the outputs -

Profiling on test script for `TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL5_Mine` -

```
Array
(
    [TeraWurfl ->__construct] => Array
        (
            [time] => 9.0599060058594E-5
            [calls] => 8
        )

    [TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL5_Mine ->__construct] => Array
        (
            [time] => 4.3630599975586E-5
            [calls] => 4
        )

    [TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL5_Mine ->connect] => Array
        (
            [time] => 0.00010228157043457
            [calls] => 6
        )

    [TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL5_Mine ->rebuildCacheTable] => Array
        (
            [time] => 7.8678131103516E-6
            [calls] => 1
        )

    [show_profile] => Array
        (
            [time] => 1.7881393432617E-5
            [calls] => 1
        )

)
```

But for the existing class `TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL5`, I did not get the function call details, which is strange again -

```
Array
(
    [show_profile] => Array
        (
            [time] => 0.00024199485778809
            [calls] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: You're using `$DB_CONNECTOR = 'MySQL5_Mine'` but the file name is `TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL5Mine.php`, e.g. without the extra underscore. Perhaps this is causing the problem? I guess you have misnamed either the file name or the class.

Comment: @BArt this happened while preparing the question. thanks for pointing out. But the code does not have this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases you can debug the flow even without `xdebug` by using:

```
declare(ticks=1);
register_tick_function(function(){
    $debug = debug_backtrace();
    echo "Running on line " . $debug[0]['line'] . " in file " . $debug[0]['file'] . "\n"; 
});
```

**Edit:**
*Actually, my example was bad, so I only left the important part.*

Comment: Thanks, I set up profiling in my code and posted the output in section **Update #2 - profiling output**. Please see if you can help

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir! profiling saved me. An fatal error suppressed by error suppression operator `@` was hiding the problem area and hence not returning to the caller. I assumed that setting `error_reporting(-1)` and `ini_set("display_errors","On")` would anyway show all errors but that was not the case.

Comment: I compared the differences in profiler outputs for the two database connectors (the existing one and the new one I modified). The fatal error was happening inside __desctruct() method of the new class and hence it was not showing in profiler output. However I am not sure exactly when does the profiler output does not show a function. I just found that if there is no line of executable code inside a function (say an empty function), it does not show in the prof output. Why is this so? What is the point?